# What is depth information among an image?

Tags: projection, point-clouds, depth, lidar

Given pixel location (x,y) in an image, how to get the depth information of this pixel?

In other words, I just obtain (x,y) location of a 3D point in the image plane using projection matrix and now I want to obtain a depth map. What pixel values should I take to obtain such depth map?

NB : I am trying to follow this code :
 !(https://github.com/balcilar/DenseDepthMap)

Comment: let P denotes homogeneous coordinate of LIDAR points. and p denotes homogeneous coordinate of image ponts. where Zp=K[R|t]P, K denotes projection matrix.  the Z here is denoting the scale factor/depth factor of a pixel.  For each projected image (x,y) just assign the actual Intensity with the Z value will do.  The resulting image is the depth image. FYI, this cv::Mat needs to be double format.   The most common way is to use a term called baseline to convert them to uint8/uchar format. Read more on multi-view geomerty plz

Comment: But what is the depth factor of a pixel? This is what I am asking . How to get the Z

Comment: oh are you asking how to infer color code of a depth image?  AKA color code to real metric measure?

Comment: You question isnt exactly ask to the point. So assume it is color depth to greyscale disparity conversations, you may refer to this code http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~nk752/depthMapTut.html#Step%204. this is how color depth map is generated. Inverse this step should give the actual disparity you wanted.